# How to fade in an image gradually with pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I work with pygame and I have to fade in an image.

I've tried guides from the internet, but none of them work.

I use `+=`, but the first frame (fps is set to 120, I identified this using fps 1) is fully transparent and the second frame is quickly fully opaque. I need to have a fade in effect instead of this.

I have this code:

```
i = 0
for i in range (0, 255):
    i = 0
    i += 1
    dvd.set_alpha(i)
    screen.blit(dvd, dvdrect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

The line below doesn't work.

```
pygame.time.delay(30)
```

Comment: Please create a [mre] so that we can observe your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> i = 0
> for i in range (0, 255):
>     i = 0
>     i += 1
>     dvd.set_alpha(i)
> ```

This is not how a `for` loop works. You are calling `dvd.set_alpha(1)` 255 times.

Maybe you meant to use this instead:

```
for i in range (0, 255):
    dvd.set_alpha(i)
```

Which calls `dvd.set_alpha(0)`, then `dvd.set_alpha(1)`, then `dvd.set_alpha(2)`, ..., then `dvd.set_alpha(254)`.

Note that it does *not* call `dvd.set_alpha(255)`, because the upper end of `range` is exclusive.

---

I don't know if `set_alpha` expects a float between 0 and 1, or an integer between 0 and 255 (or maybe 256?). If the former is the case, you need to call something like `dvd.set_alpha(i / 256)` when `i` goes from 0 to approximately 256, to scale it into the range from 0 to 1.

Comment: I've tried the same as you wrote (it was also Zobody's way), but the results are same.

Comment: What if you add the `pygame.time.delay(30)` back in? Did you try using `set_alpha(i / 256)` instead of `set_alpha(i)`?

Comment: Using `i = 0; i += 1` inside the `for i in ...` loop is definitely wrong.

Comment: Then that changes the FPS, and I cannot move the screen. Also, the fading still isn't there.

Comment: Forgot to mention that `pygame.time.delay(30)` does this freezing.

Comment: You still need to include `pygame.display.update()`

Comment: I know, I have it all there. But when I move this fading to another ˙while 1:`, then it works, but the fade is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing i += 1, measure the time between current frame and last frame. That will be your delta.
Now, you just simply multiply your delta value by the fade/second value. In your example, you seem to want a fade value of 255/120, so the resulting line would be:
i += delta * 255/120

Another problem that could be happening here is that alpha value might be a float/double from 0.0 to 1.0, hence making it fully opaque after you add 1 to it.

In your simple example, try adding 1/255 to see if you get your expected result.

Edit: my brain completely skipped over the fact that yes, you are setting alpha to 1 all the time. Instead of doing

```
for i in range(0,255):
    dvd.set_alpha(i)
```

I suggest doing

```
    for i in range(0,256):
dvd.set_alpha(i/256)
```

Comment: It says "delta" is not defined. Also, I've tried the second option `i += 1/255`, but I don't know if I got it right.

EDIT: Oh, I've missed your edit. I apologize :D

Comment: Well, I am not sure about specifics in python/pygame, and if you are just beginning these things it might not matter too much right now. You have to declare the variable yourself.